# Button sticking out of form

Tags: html, css, css-float, bootstrap-5, clearfix

I have a form that looks like this:

[image]

Removing the `mb-3` class does nothing to help, it just removes the spaces between the inputs. How am I supposed to ensure the button stays within the blue box?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end">Hop In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'float-end' class makes the button float to the right, so we need to add `'overflow: hidden;'` to the form container to keep it within the blue box

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255); overflow: hidden;" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end">Hop In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem here is the "Clear bug/Float bug". The newer variant of the "Clearfix" (with ":after" element) is already integrated in Bootstrap -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/clearfix/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by using `float-end` on the button which will move the button out of the normal flow and float it. 
Simply use Flexbox with `flex-direction: column` on the container by adding the classes `d-flex` and `flex-column`.
After that you can push the button to the right side by adding the class `ms-auto` to the button:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ms-auto">Hop In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ```d-block ms-auto``` classes on the ```button``` could be simpler solution.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam with `d-block` the button would span the full width of the container

Comment: No it doesn't. But it does in your above method if you remove ```ms-auto``` You should check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float using `clearfix` after float. Then it works.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Or you can write it in CSS:

```
form::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);" method="POST">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end">Hop In</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: While this works, float is the wrong class to start with and you need to add an empty element for styling purposes. That is unclean and reduces accessibility.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I was trying to fix it following his approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use float and solve it the bootstrap way, you should give the parent element the class "clearfix". This fixes the "clearfix bug" when you have bootstrap loaded.

- [Bootstrap 5.2 Documentation: "Clearfix"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/clearfix/)

I wrapped a container around the form and gave it the class "clearfix".

Since I think it's unusual to put css styles on the form-tag, I moved the styles from the form-tag to the outer container.

(Usually only the parameters needed for sending are used in a form-tag. Probably to create a more precise separation between styling and functionality. An "official rule" is not known to me at least.)

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="p-3 rounded-4 clearfix" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);">
    <form action="/user/loginattempt" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end">Hop In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong to style a form. In the end it is just an semantic container.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer, but I've never seen a styled form tag in the last few years. Most established conventions have their purpose, even if it's not a hard rule.

Comment: What convention are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

One (Bootstrap) way would be to remove the `fload-end` class from the button and wrap it inside an element with [`d-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/) and [`justify-content-end`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content).

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Hop In</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Another (Bootstrap) way would be to remove the `fload-end` class and add [`d-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/)  and [`ms-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/) classes to your button to force a `display: block;` with an automatic left-margin (`margin-left: auto;`).

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<form action="/user/loginattempt" class="p-3 rounded-4" style="background-color:rgb(192, 242, 255);" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success d-block ms-auto">Hop In</button>
</form>
```

Both methods achieve the exact same results.